# fit deep learning model using keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am new to deep learning and keras, I want to do a task which is : Train the model on the training data using 50 epochs.

I wrote this codes:

```
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.python.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

concrete_data = pd.read_csv('https://cocl.us/concrete_data')

n_cols = concrete_data.shape[1]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
          optimizer='adam')


x = concrete_data.Cement
y = concrete_data.drop('Cement', axis=1)
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3)
```

but when I want to fit my model this way :

```
model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, validation_data=(xTrain, yTrain), epochs=50)
```

I have this errors:

```
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-489dd99522b4> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, validation_data=(xTrain, yTrain), epochs=50)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:503 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:464 train_step  **
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:885 __call__
        self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:216 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + str(shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 9 but received input with shape [None, 1]
```

and my concrete data is :
[image]

and this is the shape of x and y (separated by *):
[image]
I really have no idea what is the problem.

Comment: Please give more info about your "concrete_data". Shape of it etc.. and what is the shape of your x and y ?

Comment: @BatuhanBardak Thank you. I edited the question, and I am not sure about x and y, I coded that to answer this question: Randomly split the data into a training and test sets by holding 30% of the data for testing. You can use the train_test_split helper function from Scikit-learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to change input_shape like below:

```
input_shape=(n_cols,) =>>  input_shape=(n_cols-1,)
```

In the beginning, your data have include features and target data so the shape consists of both. You need to minus 1 from that part to specify the input shape.

The other problem is you need to switch the data between `x` and `y`. I think that you want to predict `Cement` with rest of your dataset. So the `Cement` information should be stored in `y` and the rest of your dataset should be in `x`.

Also, you need to change this part of the code.

```
model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, validation_data=(xTrain, yTrain), epochs=50)
```

Using the same data on the training and validation does not have meaning. You can specify the validation ratio so the keras will make you automatically.

Comment: I editted my answer, did you switch the data of x and y variables ?